# ERROR: npm v10.5.0 is known not to run on Node.js v10.24.1. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

PS C:\Users\prajwal\OneDrive\Desktop\adorsy\p2p-lending> npm -v
ERROR: npm v10.5.0 is known not to run on Node.js v10.24.1.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR:
C:\Users\prajwal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\exit-handler.js:19
const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded``` your text``your text ```
^
`your text`
I currently have **nodejs 20** but  my project is using ** nodejs 10 **so
i installed nvm and then nodejs 10 using command **nvm install 10**
then i ran **nvm use 10.24.1**
but the problem is that even after switching from nodejs20 to nodejs10 the npm version didn't change from  npm 10 to npm 6.
i tried all methods available on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall and reinstall -

also do npm cache clean -f

```
 nvm uninstall 10
 nvm install 10
 nvm use 10.24.1
```

Comment: Thank you, had the same issue on mac with the above errormessage, after updating with `npm install -g npm`. Cache clear, uninstall an reinstall helped alot.